# Can I simulate NFC-V tag?

Tags: android, nfc, iso-15693

I'm working on a NFC application which would be using NFC-V tags with ISO 15693 specification. Unfortunately, I do not have a NFC enabled phone at the moment. I wanted to know if I can simulate the behavior of the NFC-V tags in some way. 
I know the Android developer website has a NFC Demo, which has a class called FakeTagsActivity. But, that uses NDEF messages. This will not be compatible with NFC-V and I'm not sure how to "create" a Tag object so that it can be simulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the only reasonable way to develop and test your app would be to use a real NFC-enabled device. Sending and receiving data using NfcV.transceive() is not extremely easy and it is simply to easy to make mistakes. So simulating an NfcV tag is probably much more work than it is worth, IMO.